# rails vagrant windows changes in controller delayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, vagrant

I'm running into a very weird problem with Vagrant. I believe it's something that started after I updated to Vagrant 1.6.1.

Lets say I'm opening a web page X in controller Y. If I change the view of that page and I click refresh I see the changes immediately. If I change the controller somehow and I click refresh **nothing changes**. I have to wait for around 40 seconds for the changes to take effect.

I'm running:

- Vagrant 1.6.1
- Rails 4.0.1
- Thin 1.6.1
- Windows 7

Such delays make development very slow and frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution, it's not optimal, but it lets me work.
Add this line of code to development.rb:

```
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false
```